# XCODE GCC6 Compatibility

Tags: xcode, gcc6

I downloaded the latest version of GCC (6.2.0) using homebrew. It works great from the command line (you have to make sure you really use it and not the g++ override that XCODE does)

If I try to tell XCODE to use this version of GCC as the compiler, it says it is incompatible.

Did I download the wrong thing? Is this just because it's so new?

Comment: Can Xcode even use gcc at this point? Apple dropped it years ago.

Comment: Yes you can use other compilers. Just go to Build Settings -> (all) -> Build Options -> Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C  and you can put the path there.